# Deploy with capistrano failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

When I run `cap deploy:check` everything is OK but when I run `cap:deploy` it gives me this error:

```
** [xx.xx.org :: out] fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed
** [xx.xx.org :: out] fatal: index-pack failed
```

I am using these gems:

```
gem 'capistrano','2.15.5'
gem 'capistrano-ext','1.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a git issue, not capistrano. See http://blog.dinaburg.org/2013/07/git-fails-on-large-files.html